# Find out value of Apache directive setting without access to config files?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, configuration

I'm troubleshooting a time-sensitive file upload app and suspect that the issue could be due to Apache's `KeepAliveTimeout` directive. Just called hosting support and asked them what the setting is at. They told me "it's not publicly-available information". I have shell access to the shared hosting server.

Searching for `httpd.conf` terminates without success.

Is there a way to find out what the value for the directive value is without having access to `httpd.conf`?

Comment: *Time-sensitive* and *shared hosting* do not belong together.  Get yourself a host where you have control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `httpd -V`. That wuill show you where Apache is looking for a config file(s).
You are loking for something like:

> -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="conf/httpd.conf"

There is an option to show settings but currently it's not very useful: `-S     Show the settings as parsed from the config file (currently only shows the virtualhost settings).`

Ig you have access to vhost settings then you can set `TimeOut` yourself:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#timeout

Hope that helps.

Comment: `httpd: command not found`. Could they have disabled it?

Comment: `netstat -antpl |grep 80` - there are milions of servers, doesn't have to be apache. What linux is this on? `cat /etc/issue`

Comment: Hi, please remove IPs - no need for them. Forgot that you are on the shared hosting! Anyway, as @john-kloian has mentioned 5 min would be the default timeout. You can try and see if banner is not disabled (by `telnet 0 80` and then `get / HTTP/1.0` (as John suggested) but doubt it will work.

Comment: Also, is this a PHP app?

Comment: It is. Uploading files via AJAX and pushing them to DropBox, which takes a while and that's where the issue lies. Server returns a 504 before it's done.

Comment: PHP has got it's own timeout: [PHP conf man](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php) - again, you are of of luck as that's in `php.ini`. Is the move to VPS possible? They are quite cheap now.

Answer (score 1):

Apache and NGinx both use 5 minutes as their default keepalive timeout.

Most likely you do not have access to that information - it would be contained in server's config file - normally not accessible by customers if the hosting company is even remotely on the ball.  You may be able to find out which server with simple network tools like nmap.

You could use telnet maybe:

```
telnet host 80
```

once in telnet try:

```
get / HTTP/1.0
```

In the response look for the line beginning

```
Server:
```

You could list the server's process with 'ps ax' - you may or may not get back a complete list.  Apache shows up as apache2 these days or maybe httpd depending on the flavor of OS.

Using curl you may be able to craft a command-line that will exercise the keepalive timeout and prove it one way or another.  I'm at a loss at the moment of what that would look like unfortunately.

Comment: Apache uses 5 seconds (not minutes) as the default KeepAliveTimeout these days, fwiw. I don't think it was ever 5 minutes.